# How to output a variable from a Servlet to JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to output a variable defined in a Servlet to a JSP, and I just can't do it!

Here's my code:

```
MainServlet:

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package DAO;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(name = "MainServlet", urlPatterns = {"/MainServlet"})
public class MainServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        request.setAttribute("msg", "Bloody Hell"); // Here <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }

}
```

index.jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>BlueBank</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Whatever: ${msg}</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

[That "msg" variable does not appear. When I test it on netbeans, the "msg" variable does not work. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jS1x3.png)

Comment: Why should it appear? What relation does your servlet have with the JSP you've shown?

Comment: Are you required to use a raw servlet instead of something more manageable like Spring MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your servlet assuming your jsp is in the root context, use something like

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    // response.setContentType("text/html");
    request.setAttribute("msg", "Bloody Hell");
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").include(request, response);
}
```

And then access your servlet url (and it will set the attribute and then include the index jsp).

Comment: My WEB-INF was incorrect, and I was accessing as index.jsp on the URL instead of MainServlet (Yeah, pretty stupid, but now it's ok). Thanks for your help!